# How to use a homescreen widget button to shutdown a service?

Tags: android, button, service, widget, shutdown

I have a button whose WidgetProvider kicks off a service with a
PendingIntent. That works just fine. How do I similarly attach an
event handler to the button so that when it is pressed a second time,
it shuts the service down? Is there an appropriate pattern to follow
for something like this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `getBroadcast()` `PendingIntent`, where the `BroadcastReceiver` calls `stopService()`.

Or, use a `getService()` `PendingIntent`, where you send a command to your service that has the service call `stopSelf()`.

Or, switch the service to an `IntentService`, so it shuts down automatically, if that is a better service implementation for your scenario.

Comment: Thanks! I went with your second suggestion. I learned about Intent actions and how you can switch on them...